# Data on a Extended Application class lost when app is closed

Tags: android, static, ondestroy

I´ve an Android Application that holds some static objects on an class that extends Application class, using the same approach as exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008253/android-application-class-globals-instance-or-static).

The objects that is hold by this class is shared and manipulated between all activities on my app.

Everything works well, but, some time ago, I noticed that when the application runs on backgroud for some time, when it´s restored, the data that was stored on the extended class has gone, and the app starts to throws a lot of NullReference exceptions.

I think that this happens because of the application was being temporary destroyed by the OS, to be recreated when we need to use it again.

So, how could I handle this scenario? Is there any way to discover that the application is being temporary destroyed, without subscribing to the onDestroy event of an Activity? On a test that I did, the onDestroy event was not called when I asked the background process of my app to being stopped.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine when the proccess will be killed, so you always should store important data somewhere(sd-card for example) and restore it in onCreate() method of your App class.

Also take a look at onLowMemory() and onTrimMemory(), release all unnecesary data in memory to help the OS prevent destroying your app, cause one of the reason to determinate your app is a lack of memory.

Comment: I can't see method "onTrimMemory" of Application class. Can you give me brief details of it?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to tell when you need to persist data that you store in static variables like that. There's no callback that the systems notifies you about this, at least to my knowledge.

So you should only use static variables to store temporary data, or cache data accessed from peristent sources. I've faced this problem in many of my projects, and I always ended up using intents / shared prefs / sqlite / etc. to reliable store data across Activities.